# Paypal mass payment by using Receiver Account Id

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, masspay

I want to implement paypal mass payment in my portal. I'm using paypal adaptive payment and i have my customers paypal account id like RPSE782P3LRMU. How can i process mass payment by using account id instead of email address?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments Pay API now supports PayPal account ID.  Look for AccountID.

PayRequest.receiverList.receiver(n).accountId

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/adaptive-payments/PayPal_Adaptive_Payments_API_Release_Notes_1_8_4/#CC